# dunglas mercure server / javascript EventSource withCredentials : mercureAutorisation cookie not transmited

Tags: javascript, firefox, symfony4, mercure

Making a mercure /hub dispaching Updates with symfony 4.4 works fine until I dont try using credentials with mercureAuthorization cookie.

As soon as I add {withCredentials: true} in EventSource, firefox kicks out event source request connection with "CORS missing" (whereas chrome doesn't)

```
'same origin' policy don't allow consulting 'http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure ... ' Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing
```

Plus, I'm supposed to get the mercureAuthorization cookie passed from my page request to the event source request, but it isn't.

Here is my homePage cookie :

```
Set-Cookie: mercureAuthorization=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InN1YnNjcmliZSI6WyJodHRwOlwvXC9ub3RpZnkuY29tXC9wYXJhbmdvblwvdGVhbSJdfX0.e5YOGcOx-s-8nn2lbseqcVlk18dVEvgZIoKrDCEureA; path=/.well-known/mercure; httponly; samesite=strict;
```

My event source Request

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure?topic=http://notify.com/
```

No Set-Coockie indside.

EDIT: I finally manage to fix it by working on the same domain !
So know I run the mercure server with:

```
--adress:'www.mydomain.test:3000/.well-known/mercure ... '
```

Posting from

```
'www.mydomain.test/' for exemple
```

Set-Cookie:

```
'return new Cookie('mercureAuthorization', $token, 
  (exp) 0, 
  (path) '/.well-known/mercure', 
  (domain) null, 
  (secure) false, 
  (httponly) true, 
  (raw) false, 
  (same-site) 'Strict'
);'
```

Comment: The default behaviour applied by Chrome is slightly more permissive than an explicit SameSite=Lax as it will allow certain cookies to be sent on top-level POST requests. You can see the exact details on the [blink-dev announcement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/AknSSyQTGYs/YKBxPCScCwAJ). This is intended as a temporary mitigation, you should still be fixing your cross-site cookies to use SameSite=None; Secure.

Comment: Thanks for your help, even though i think i've tried everything from SameSite=none/lax/strict with and without secure. 
I'll give it a shot one more time just in case. 

May i need to set-up mercure domain as https? (hard stuff in local env...)